# Wordpress website all urls have pagination

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have created a **wordpress** website and i have noticed that when i type /page/1 on any page it shows the exact same content.
This is happening on all pages and really bugging me.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Theme? There may be updates to fix this if you have Woo installed go up to 2.1.1

```
<?php if (have_posts()) {$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; query_posts("category_name=Blog&paged=$paged"); } ?>
```

It may replace code like this that may be there normally...

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=Blog&showposts=10'); ?>
```